# (React) useParams getting the id and displaying from the list

Tags: reactjs, undefined

using the useParams for getting the value from a page, I have the id but I'm trying to display the shop array with that specific id

```
const shopContext = useContext(ShopContext);
const { shop } = shopContext;
const { id } = useParams();
{shop.map(sho => (
                    <ShopBanner
                        key={sho.id}
                        // id={id}
                        shop={shop.find(sh => sh.id === id)}
                    />
                ))}
```

from the ShopBanner.js

```
function ShopBanner({ shop }) {
    const { name, image, description, phone, address, short } = shop;
```

shows me the error "TypeError: shop is undefined"

Comment: Are you using the `useParams()` hook in react-router? React doesn't have a `useParams()` hook packaged by default.

Comment: it turns out that the id was a string so I had to convert it to an integer and it's working now

Answer (score 0):

There is an typo in filter function..

```
shop={shop.find(sho => sho.id === id)
```

Comment: this doesn't help

Comment: Pls console.log(id)..And post the result

Comment: Also please post the code where you have declared route..

Answer (score 0):

it turns out that the id was a string so I had to convert it to an integer and it's working now